# How to stop $ / being stripped of a string being inserted into a file with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

**The Aim**
I am trying to write a bash script to automate the setup of a Raspbian system.  This includes setting a custom prompt for all users.
I need to change one line in the /etc/bashrc file.

I want to comment out the existing line and add a new line immediately after it.

**What I have done**
I have written a sed regix command that correctly finds the line.  It comments the existing line and adds the new line immediately after.  All good except that all of the "/" "$" some text and probably other important stuff is stripped out by sed.

I have tried various combinations of back ticks,", brackets etc but I haven't found a solution.

**The Problem**

I know that all of the active chars in sed need to be delimited.  I entered the line to be inserted into an on-line regex editor 
to ensure I had the right slashes in the right places to create an inactive line.

So the problem is that the delimiting failed completely.  sed stripped out a lot of regex type characters and plain text.

**The Code**
Here is the code to test the find/comment/insert sed statement

```
#!/bin/bash
# Setup of bash prompt

# Define custom prompt
custom_prompt="  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[36;40m\]\u\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[36m\]\h\[\e[m\]: \[\e[92m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[92m\]\\$\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]>\[\e[m\]'"
# delimited version of the prompt
sed_custom_prompt="  PS1=\' \${debian_chroot:\+\(\$debian_chroot\)}\\[\\e[36;40m\\]\\u\\[\\e[m\\]\\[\\e[93m\\]@\\[\\e[m\\]\\[\\e[36m\\]\\h\\[\\e[m\\]: \\[\\e[92m\\]\\w\\[\\e[m\\] \\[\\e[92m\\]\\\\\$\\[\\e[m\\]$'"


### Setup Bash Prompt
# relevant section from /etc/bashrc is:
# if ! [ -n "${SUDO_USER}" -a -n "${SUDO_PS1}" ]; then
#    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ ' # this is the line I want to subsitute
# fi

#This is the desired outcome. The original line is commented out. The new line is active
# if ! [ -n "${SUDO_USER}" -a -n "${SUDO_PS1}" ]; then
#   # PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ ' # this is the line I want to subsitute
#    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[36;40m\]\u\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[36m\]\h\[\e[m\]: \[\e[92m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[92m\]\\$\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]>\[\e[m\]'
# fi


# this is the test sed command that works on a test copy of bash in ~
# it comments the target line then inserts abcdef on the next line.  It works as expected.
#sed -i 's/\^*PS1=.*/#&\nabcdef/' ~/bash.bashrc
# I tried this command but all the back slashes and other characters were stripped off.
sed  -i 's/\^*PS1=.*/#&\n'"$sed_custom_prompt"'/' ~/bash.bashrc


Actual faulty file output after sed.  Note that symbols and other text is stripped off.

if ! [ -n "${SUDO_USER}" -a -n "${SUDO_PS1}" ]; then
   #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
  PS1='[e[36;40m][e[m][e[93m]@[e[m][e[36m]h[e[m]: [e[92m]w[e[m] [e[92m]$[e[m][e[93m]>[e[m]

fi
```

Here is the sample file/data stored in `/~/bash.bashrc` that the above code acts on for testing purposes:

```
if ! [ -n "${SUDO_USER}" -a -n "${SUDO_PS1}" ]; then
   PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '

fi
```

The code above includes a lot of notes.  The following is the same code with minimal notes.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This is the line I want to insert, but sed inteprets it.  
custom_prompt="  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[36;40m\]\u\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[36m\]\h\[\e[m\]: \[\e[92m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[92m\]\\$\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]>\[\e[m\]'"
# delimited version of the prompt that should be acceptable to sed, but isn't.
sed_custom_prompt="  PS1=\' \${debian_chroot:\+\(\$debian_chroot\)}\\[\\e[36;40m\\]\\u\\[\\e[m\\]\\[\\e[93m\\]@\\[\\e[m\\]\\[\\e[36m\\]\\h\\[\\e[m\\]: \\[\\e[92m\\]\\w\\[\\e[m\\] \\[\\e[92m\\]\\\\\$\\[\\e[m\\]$'"

#This is the sed statement that:
#  -finds "PS1="
#  -adds a prefix "#" to comment out the existing line
#  -adds a suffix that begins with a line feed to insert the new line.
sed  -i 's/\^*PS1=.*/#&\n'"$sed_custom_prompt"'/' ~/bash.bashrc
```

**The Question**

So the problem and the question is: How do I fix this??
I am beginning to think that sed is not the right tool for this job. 
Maybe I need to switch to perl.

** The Solution**
@kamel cuk below provided the key to solving this problem.  The delimiting I manually added to the $custom_prompt variable was wrong.  Kamal provided a sed statement that correctly delimited the variable.  The following statements produce the correct result:

```
sed_custom_prompt=$(<<<"$custom_prompt" sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')
sed  -i 's/\^*PS1=.*/#&\n'"$sed_custom_prompt"'/' ~/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: `d various combinations of back ticks` - don't use backticks. `Here is the sample file/data s` - what should the output look like? `s/` - you are aware you can specify _any_ character after `s` command in sed? `sed 's~a~b~'`

Comment: The desired output is shown in the code comments.  The line to be inserted is shown in the top of the code as a variable.

Comment: You want the line `# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ ' # this is the line I want to subsitute` to stay in the output?

Comment: That is the original line I want to comment out.  That part of sed works. It fails to correctly insert the new line because it interprets the symbols in the new line and in doing so, it strips out characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the following works:

```
cat <<'EOF' |
if ! [ -n "${SUDO_USER}" -a -n "${SUDO_PS1}" ]; then
   PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '

fi
EOF
sed 's/\([[:space:]]\+\)PS1=.*/\1#&\n\1PS1='\''[e[36;40m][e[m][e[93m]@[e[m][e[36m]h[e[m]: [e[92m]w[e[m] [e[92m]$[e[m][e[93m]>[e[m]'\''/'
```

and will output:

```
if ! [ -n "${SUDO_USER}" -a -n "${SUDO_PS1}" ]; then
   #   PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
   PS1='[e[36;40m][e[m][e[93m]@[e[m][e[36m]h[e[m]: [e[92m]w[e[m] [e[92m]$[e[m][e[93m]>[e[m]'

fi
```

Notes:

- I matched also spaces in front of `PS1=`, it looks like you want the output to be intended.
- You have to escape single ticks.
- The newline character `\n` inside `RE` expression in `s/PRE/RE/` command in `sed` is a GNU extension.
- You don't have to escape `\$` and `\(` not `\)` nor `\+` on the right side of `s` command. You have to escape `\` itself.So you could do this:

```
  custom_prompt="  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[36;40m\]\u\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[36m\]\h\[\e[m\]: \[\e[92m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[92m\]\\$\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]>\[\e[m\]'"
  # replace each \ for double \\
  sed_custom_prompt=$(<<<"$custom_prompt" sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')
  sed 's/\([[:space:]]\+\)PS1=.*/\1#&\n\1'"$sed_custom_prompt"'/'
```

Comment: This statement:  sed_custom_prompt=$(<<<"$custom_prompt" sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')  worked.  The one after didn't work. When I combined your sed statement with mine, the combination worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: It almost works.  The first section of the custom prompt:  '${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}  get stripped off by sed.  There is a $ sign further down the prompt that is almost left untouched. One \ is removed before it.  Do I need to insert \ before the $?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
a='this is variable'
cat <<EOF | sed '/5/!b;s//#&/;r /dev/stdin' <(seq 10)
this is the first added line
this line contains the variable \$a => $a <=
this line contains a backslash \\ and a dollar \$
this is the last line
EOF
```

If you do not want any shell interpretation, use:

```
cat <<\EOF | sed '/5/!b;s//#&/;r /dev/stdin' <(seq 10)
this is the first added line
this line contains the variable $a => $a <=
this line contains a backslash \ and a dollar $
this is the last line
EOF
```

N.B. The `\`before `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a coding error in your script: the line starting with `sed_custom_prompt=` misses closing quotes: just add `\'"` at the end of the line and look if you get the right output into your ~/bash.bashrc file.

Comment: If this solves the problem, consider to vote up this comment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was only a problem in that I missed those quotes when copying from the source code.  Thanks for your input, but it wasn't the problem.